# How to turn a png into the texture of a sphere JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, png

Right now I have a red sphere but instead of a color I want this to be the "texture". How would I go about doing that with javaFX?

[image]

*Edit: I have a program that creates the pictures and saves them as a png but I can't get it to save as a jpg. I don't know if there will be a difference in the syntax but it must be with png.

Comment: @Roland I've tried that but it doesn't work for me, maybe it's the fact that I'm using a png

Comment: No, that's not the problem. If you provide the code it'll be possible to help you. It's something easy todo, there are several tutorials for this. Without code nobody can help you.

Comment: @Roland I just realized I didn't save it in the right file... it works now. Thanks